# ¿Cómo condicionar un input tipo number con otro del mismo tipo?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo dos campos *input* tipo *number*, el primero se llama tarima inicial y el segundo tarima final; lo que necesito es que al elegir la cantidad en la tarima inicial el siguiente *input* pueda escribir un numero igual o mayor al inicial.

Mi código del formulario es este:

```
 <div class="input-group">
    <input type="number" id="tarimaini" name="tarimaini" min="1">
    <label class="label" for="tarini">De Tarima:</label>
 </div>
 <div class="input-group">
  <input type="number" id="tarimafin" name="tarimafin" min="1">
  <label class="label" for="tarfin">A:</label>   
 </div>
 <input type="submit" value="Crear">
 </div>
 </form>
 </div>
 </div>
 <script src="js/formulario.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Nos compartirías que has intentado pro favor?, lee [ask]

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#tarimaini').change(function() {
    $('#tarimafin').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="number" id="tarimaini" name="tarimaini" min="1">
    <label class="label" for="tarini">De Tarima:</label>
 </div>
 <div class="input-group">
  <input type="number" id="tarimafin" name="tarimafin" min="1">
  <label class="label" for="tarfin">A:</label>   
 </div>
 <input type="submit" value="Crear">
 </div>
 </form>
 </div>
 </div>
 <script src="js/formulario.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Listo amigo, tengo entendido que es exactamente lo que buscabas, al elegir cierta cantidad en automatico se pasa al input de abajo. Saludos.

(Dale a "Ejecutar" para que lo veas, por si acaso)

Comment: ¿Qué tal si basándonos en [answer] le explicas el código por favor?

Comment: Tu respuesta está bien, pero no le explicas al usuario que es lo que haces. Que pasa si el usuario no está utilizando JQuery??

Comment: @EraldoCoil gracias amigo se ve bien solo me dices como habilito jquery para que tenga efecto el script porfa, he usado muy poco jquery

Answer (score 0):

Hola carlos te dejo una opcion para lo que necesitas , tome tu mismo HTML , lo que podes hacer primero es referenciar ambos inputs , en este caso lo hizo por su ID como veras y como necesitas que la tarima final en la seleccion sea menor o igual que la tarima inicial solo setie el atributo `min`  al valor actual del input que contiene las tarimas iniciales , esto se ejecuta cuando se escucha un cambio en el segundo input , con el evento `change`, espero te sirve , saludos

```js
const tarifaInicial = document.getElementById('tarimaini')
const tarifaFinal  = document.getElementById('tarimafin')

tarifaFinal.addEventListener('change',()=>{
    tarifaFinal.setAttribute('min',tarifaInicial.value)
     
})
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="number" id="tarimaini" name="tarimaini" min="1">
    <label class="label" for="tarini">De Tarima:</label>
 </div>
 <div class="input-group">
  <input type="number" id="tarimafin" name="tarimafin" min="1">
  <label class="label" for="tarfin">A:</label>   
 </div>
 <input type="submit" value="Crear">
 </div>
 </form>
 </div>
 </div>
```